# Proper organization and transformation of objects

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, ienumerable

I have a complex SQL query that returns a table like this:

[image]

I have it described by this object - `IEnumerable<Invoice>` where:

```
public partial class Invoice
{
    public string DocumentNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DocumentDate { get; set; }
    public string DocumentReference { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Certificate { get; set; }
}
```

The peculiarity of the set of these objects is that they are grouped by the first three fields (if they are the same), the remaining fields are different.

My task is to implement a hierarchical representation of this data, which should look something like this:

[image]

I decided for myself that my final view-object should have the following structure - `Dictionary<InvoiceHeader, List<InvoiceHierarchi>>` where:

```
public class InvoiceHeader
{
   public string DocumentNumber { get; set; }
   public DateTime? DocumentDate { get; set; }
   public string DocumentReference { get; set; }
}

public class InvoiceHierarchi
{
   public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
   public string ProductCode { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public string Certificate { get; set; }
}
```

**Question #1**: Can I write LINQ query that converts `IEnumerable<Invoice>` to `Dictionary<InvoiceHeader, List<InvoiceHierarchi>>` and how to do it right?

**Question #2**: In general, did I choose the right approach to solve my task?

Comment: I would perhaps just have a List<InvoiceHeader / Invoice> - Where Invoice contains a List<InvoiceLines> or something similar. Then you can easier make filtering / sorting on the frontend instead of working with a dictionary. Try google Order/Orderlines. Sounds pretty much like a similar issue :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I write LINQ query that converts `IEnumerable<Invoice>` to
>   `Dictionary<InvoiceHeader, List<InvoiceHierarchi>>` and how to do it
>   right?

Yes, you can. Try group invoices by `InvoiceHeader` and convert the result using [`ToDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToDictionary__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__) method

```cs
var invoices = new List<Invoice>();
var result = invoices.GroupBy(i => new InvoiceHeader
{
    DocumentDate = i.DocumentDate,
    DocumentNumber = i.DocumentNumber,
    DocumentReference = i.DocumentReference
}).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(i => new InvoiceHierarchi
{
    Certificate = i.Certificate,
    SerialNumber = i.SerialNumber,
    ProductCode = i.ProductCode,
    Description = i.Description
}).ToList());
```

Another option is to use [`ToLookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToLookup__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__) method

```cs
var anotherResult = invoices.ToLookup(i => new InvoiceHeader
    {
        DocumentDate = i.DocumentDate,
        DocumentNumber = i.DocumentNumber,
        DocumentReference = i.DocumentReference
    },
    i => new InvoiceHierarchi
    {
        Certificate = i.Certificate,
        SerialNumber = i.SerialNumber,
        ProductCode = i.ProductCode,
        Description = i.Description
    });
```

To properly use an `InvoiceHeader` as a `Dictionary` key you should override [`GetHashCode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=netframework-4.8) and [`Equals()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netframework-4.8) methods for this class, or implelement [`IEquatable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=netframework-4.8) interface

```cs
public class InvoiceHeader : IEquatable<InvoiceHeader>
{
    public string DocumentNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DocumentDate { get; set; }
    public string DocumentReference { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return DocumentNumber.GetHashCode() ^ DocumentDate.GetHashCode() ^ DocumentReference.GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Equals(InvoiceHeader other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
            return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return true;

        return DocumentNumber == other.DocumentNumber && 
               Nullable.Equals(DocumentDate, other.DocumentDate) &&
               DocumentReference == other.DocumentReference;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((InvoiceHeader)obj);
    }
}
```

You can get a warning, that non-readonly property is used in `GetHashCode()`, because it's not recommended to use `GetHashCode()` with mutable objects, since the state of object can be changed, but hash remains the same

> You can override `GetHashCode()` for immutable reference types. In
>   general, for mutable reference types, you should override
>   `GetHashCode()` only if:
>
> You can compute the hash code from fields that are not mutable;
>
> You can ensure that the hash code of a mutable object
>   does not change while the object is contained in a collection that
>   relies on its hash code.
>
> Otherwise, you might think that the mutable object is lost in the hash table.

So, it's better to make any (or all) properties of `InvoiceHeader` as readonly, initialize them from constructor and use to get a hash code

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very valuable to me, but as a result I get `List<Dictionary<InvoiceHeader, List<InvoiceHierarchi>>>`

Comment: How does your source data, `IEnumerable<Invoice>` is declared and did you group it? `ToDictionary` method returns `Dictionary<InvoiceHeader, List<InvoiceHierarchi>>`, it can't return a list of dictionaries. `ToList()` call is used to evaluate a `Select` result into `List<InvoiceHierarchi>` for dictionary value, not the dictionary itself. Maybe you've missed some braces?

Comment: Yes, you're right, my data source is `IEnumerable<Invoice>`. The destination should be `Dictionary<InvoiceHeader, List<InvoiceHierarchi>>`. In fact, each group in the source (part of the data including the fields: `DocumentDate, DocumentNumber, DocumentReference`) must present a `key`, and the rest of the data - `vale`( is a collection). I was just wondering whether it is possible to do this with LINQ or if I need to write my processing list.

Comment: @РоманТимохов the first code sample returns you an expected result, `InvoiceHeader` is a key in dictionary and `List<InvoiceHierarchi>` is a value. `ToLookup()` returns the same structure

Comment: Let's try to look at the example in the first picture. Block of lines 1, 2, 3 should be represented as one object `Dictionary<InvoiceHeader, List<InvoiceHierarchi>>`(since fields `DocumentDate, DocumentNumber, DocumentReference` are the same, they must submit one `key`), and the right block is `value` in the form of a `List<InvoiceHierarchi>`. As a result of processing lines 1, 2, 3(in the first pic), I get one object `Dictionary<InvoiceHeader, List<InvoiceHierarchi>>`, where `value.Count` will be = 3. Your answer will return three objects `Dictionary<InvoiceHeader, List<InvoiceHierarchi>>`

Comment: @РоманТимохов I see, got it. `InvoiceHeader` should override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods to properly used as key, I'll update an answer. It's hard to imagine the situation without the data sample